# Changing table format using CSS only

Tags: css, html-table

I have an HTML table that is generated by clicking on the map. The table format is like this.

[image: Table]

I want to transform the above table to look like this using CSS only.

[image: Desired_format]

Can anyone reflect on how this can be done?

The CSS in my HTML file is:

```
<style type="text/css">
        table.fInfo, table.fInfo td, table.fInfo th {
                border:1px solid #ddd;
                border-collapse:collapse;
                margin:0;
                padding:0;
                font-size: 90%;
                padding:.2em .1em;
        }
        table.fInfo th{
            padding:.2em .2em;
                text-transform:uppercase;
                font-weight:bold;
                background:#eee;
        }
        table.fInfo td{
                background:#fff;
        }
        table.fInfo tr.odd td{
                background:#eee;
        }
        table.fInfo caption{
                text-align:left;
                font-size:100%;
                font-weight:bold;
                text-transform:uppercase;
                padding:.2em .2em;
        }
  </style>
```

Comment: If is a table why don't change the table structure?

Comment: Provide a _proper_ [mre] of issues like this. People should not have to _guess_ what the actual HTML you want this CSS to apply could probably be.

Answer (score 0):

Change your Table structure to `tr > td,td` And for highlithing the first td you can use a class. Like that:

```css
        table.fInfo, table.fInfo td, table.fInfo th {
                border:1px solid #ddd;
                border-collapse:collapse;
                margin:0;
                padding:0;
                font-size: 90%;
                padding:.2em .1em;
        }
        table.fInfo th{
            padding:.2em .2em;
                text-transform:uppercase;
                font-weight:bold;
                background:#eee;
        }
        table.fInfo td{
                background:#fff;
        }
        table.fInfo tr.odd td{
                background:#eee;
        }
        table.fInfo caption{
                text-align:left;
                font-size:100%;
                font-weight:bold;
                text-transform:uppercase;
                padding:.2em .2em;
        }

table.fInfo td {
  padding:10px;
  text-align:center;
  
}

table.fInfo .newTitle {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<table class="fInfo">
  <tr>
    <td class="newTitle">Var 1</td>
    <td>Val 1</td>
  </tr>    
  <tr>
    <td class="newTitle">Var 2</td>
    <td>Val 2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```